# NPM run build error

Tags: node.js, npm, webpack, react-router, babeljs

When I run `npm run build` I get an error. I will get a `dist` folder.

```
ERROR in   Error: Child compilation failed:
  Entry module not found: Error: Can't resolve '/Users/jurdekker/Desktop/OnWeb/O  nWeb.react/Sisketeers/dist/index.html' in '/Users/jurdekker/Desktop/OnWeb/OnWe  b.react/Sisketeers':
  Error: Can't resolve '/Users/jurdekker/Desktop/OnWeb/OnWeb.react/Sisketeers/di  st/index.html' in '/Users/jurdekker/Desktop/OnWeb/OnWeb.react/Sisketeers'

  - compiler.js:76
    [Sisketeers]/[html-webpack-plugin]/lib/compiler.js:76:16

  - Compiler.js:304 compile
    [Sisketeers]/[webpack]/lib/Compiler.js:304:11

  - Compiler.js:514 applyPluginsAsync.err
    [Sisketeers]/[webpack]/lib/Compiler.js:514:14

  - Tapable.js:202 next
    [Sisketeers]/[tapable]/lib/Tapable.js:202:11

  - CachePlugin.js:78 Compiler.<anonymous>
    [Sisketeers]/[webpack]/lib/CachePlugin.js:78:5

  - Tapable.js:206 Compiler.applyPluginsAsyncSeries
    [Sisketeers]/[tapable]/lib/Tapable.js:206:13

  - Compiler.js:511 compilation.seal.err
    [Sisketeers]/[webpack]/lib/Compiler.js:511:11

  - Tapable.js:195 Compilation.applyPluginsAsyncSeries
    [Sisketeers]/[tapable]/lib/Tapable.js:195:46

  - Compilation.js:671 self.applyPluginsAsync.err
    [Sisketeers]/[webpack]/lib/Compilation.js:671:19

  - Tapable.js:195 Compilation.applyPluginsAsyncSeries
    [Sisketeers]/[tapable]/lib/Tapable.js:195:46

  - Compilation.js:662 self.applyPluginsAsync.err
    [Sisketeers]/[webpack]/lib/Compilation.js:662:11

  - Tapable.js:195 Compilation.applyPluginsAsyncSeries
    [Sisketeers]/[tapable]/lib/Tapable.js:195:46

  - Compilation.js:657 self.applyPluginsAsync.err
    [Sisketeers]/[webpack]/lib/Compilation.js:657:10

  - Tapable.js:195 Compilation.applyPluginsAsyncSeries
    [Sisketeers]/[tapable]/lib/Tapable.js:195:46

  - Compilation.js:653 sealPart2
    [Sisketeers]/[webpack]/lib/Compilation.js:653:9

  - Tapable.js:195 Compilation.applyPluginsAsyncSeries
    [Sisketeers]/[tapable]/lib/Tapable.js:195:46

  - Compilation.js:596 Compilation.seal
    [Sisketeers]/[webpack]/lib/Compilation.js:596:8

  - Compiler.js:508 applyPluginsParallel.err
    [Sisketeers]/[webpack]/lib/Compiler.js:508:17

  - Tapable.js:289
    [Sisketeers]/[tapable]/lib/Tapable.js:289:11

  - Compilation.js:498 _addModuleChain
    [Sisketeers]/[webpack]/lib/Compilation.js:498:11

  - Compilation.js:381 errorAndCallback.bail
    [Sisketeers]/[webpack]/lib/Compilation.js:381:4

  - Compilation.js:404 moduleFactory.create
    [Sisketeers]/[webpack]/lib/Compilation.js:404:13

  - NormalModuleFactory.js:235 factory
    [Sisketeers]/[webpack]/lib/NormalModuleFactory.js:235:20

  - NormalModuleFactory.js:60 resolver
    [Sisketeers]/[webpack]/lib/NormalModuleFactory.js:60:20

  - NormalModuleFactory.js:127 asyncLib.parallel
    [Sisketeers]/[webpack]/lib/NormalModuleFactory.js:127:20

  - async.js:3874
    [Sisketeers]/[async]/dist/async.js:3874:9

  - async.js:473
    [Sisketeers]/[async]/dist/async.js:473:16

  - async.js:1048 iteratorCallback
    [Sisketeers]/[async]/dist/async.js:1048:13

  - async.js:958
    [Sisketeers]/[async]/dist/async.js:958:16

  - async.js:3871
    [Sisketeers]/[async]/dist/async.js:3871:13


Child html-webpack-plugin for "index.html":

    ERROR in Entry module not found: Error: Can't resolve '/Users/jurdekker/Desktop/OnWeb/OnWeb.react/Sisketeers/dist/index.html' in '/Users/jurdekker/Desktop/OnWeb/OnWeb.react/Sisketeers'
Child extract-text-webpack-plugin node_modules/extract-text-webpack-plugin/dist node_modules/css-loader/index.js!node_modules/sass-loader/lib/loader.js!sass/main.scss:
       [0] ./node_modules/css-loader!./node_modules/sass-loader/lib/loader.js!./sass/main.scss 1.27 kB {0} [built]
        + 1 hidden module
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 2
npm ERR! onweb-sisketeers@1.0.0 build: `webpack`
npm ERR! Exit status 2
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the onweb-sisketeers@1.0.0 build script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/jurdekker/.npm/_logs/2018-01-19T17_33_37_060Z-debug.log
Jurs-MacBook-Pro:Sisketeers jurdekker$
```

I get this error the whole time but I do not know if it is up to webpack or something else. in my `dist` folder I get a `.html` file with the same error. I myself do not understand npm so if someone can give more information about it I would like to hear it.

---

Update 22-01-2018

this is my webpack config, I do not see anything wrong. maybe you find something?

```html
const path = require('path');

const ExtractTextPlugin = require("extract-text-webpack-plugin");
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');


module.exports = {
    entry : './src/index.js',
    output : {
        filename : 'bundle.js',
        path : path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist')
    },
    devtool : 'inline-source-map',
    devServer : {
     // contentBase : './dist'
     historyApiFallback: true
     },
    module : {
        rules : [
            {
                test : /\.(js|jsx)$/,
                exclude : /(node_modules|bower_components)/,
                use : {
                    loader : 'babel-loader',
                    options : {
                        presets : [ 'env', 'react', 'stage-2' ]
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                test : /\.scss$/,
                use : ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
                                                    use : [ {
                                                        loader : "css-loader"
                                                    }, {
                                                        loader : "sass-loader"
                                                    } ],
                                                    // use style-loader in
                                                    // development
                                                    fallback : "style-loader"
                                                })
            }
        ]
    },
    plugins : [
        new ExtractTextPlugin("styles.css"),
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            template : path.join(path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'), 'index.html')
        })
    ],
    resolve : {
        extensions : [ '.js', '.jsx' ]
    }
};
```

Comment: You should be clear if the whitespace in the paths is a logging or copy-and-paste artefact or actually the output you are getting. If the latter, I think you have a place to start looking.

Comment: npm run build will execute the scripts.build entry in package.json - find out what command that executes and go from there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Webpack can't find some module. Need to check your webpack configs

Comment: I update it, can you check if my webpack config is fine?